# Use of "of" or "by"

Tags: prepositions, determiners

Which one of this two sentences is the most correct:

> "This system is heterogenous, thus composed of processors and coprocessors."

or

> "This system is heterogenous, thus composed by processors and coprocessors"

I have the impression that to use 'of' in the first sentence we needed to specify the number of processors/coprocessors, for example:

> "This system is heterogenous, thus composed of two processors and four coprocessors".

Comment: "composed by" is to indicate which composer composed the piece of music "Messiah was composed by Handel". In this sense it should not be used in the way you propose to use it. (Also, CPU & GPU are abbreviations and should be capitalized.)

Comment: A question like this is much easier to answer if you give us more than a short clause to work with. Both _of_ and _by_ can be used with _composed_; I found these two examples in published books: _"A vegetable is composed of a root, stem, leaves, flowers, fruits, and seeds"_ and _"A virtual module is composed by a module from the heterogeneous system modeled by the virtual architecture and a wrapper_. You don't do anyone any favors by asking a question with only such a small fragment to work with.

Comment: @J.R. I will add more context.

Comment: My guts feeling tells me that you probably wanted to say, *"... contains two processors and four coprocessors"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Composed *of*" means 'made up of' or 'formed of' or 'consisting of'.

"Composed *by*" means 'written by' in the sense of *writing music*. Just the word 'heterogenous' leads me to the conclusion that your statement has *nada** to do with music.

So, what you're looking for is "composed *of*":

> This system is heterogenous, thus **made up of** processors and coprocessors."

as opposed to:

> This system is heterogenous, thus **a piece of music written by** processors and coprocessors."

Comment: Yep, it makes sense, thanks for answering. Although, as "J.R" pointed out there is some examples with the use by on the literature e.g. ""A virtual module is composed by a module from the heterogeneous system modeled by the virtual architecture and a wrapper"

Comment: http://bit.ly/1mKIr3U ... I'd consider using 'by' in that context as just some attempt to sound more rehearsed in the language; it doesn't sound correct to me. :)